# How to implement UserPasswordException on Liferay 7.4

Tags: java, liferay

I need to implement this code but it is deprecated, how can I change it for liferay 7.4? It is currently in liferay 6.2 and we are migrating to 7.4, I have thought about it but I do not understand the changes on this class. Can somebody help me?

```
                    errorKey = "changepassword.error";
                    SessionErrors.add(actionRequest, e.getClass(), e);
                    //TODO
                    switch (upe.getMessage()){
                    case UserPasswordException.PASSWORD_ALREADY_USED:
                        errorKey = "that-password-has-already-been-used-please-enter-in-a-different-password";
                        break;
                    case UserPasswordException.PASSWORD_CONTAINS_TRIVIAL_WORDS:
                        errorKey = "that-password-uses-common-words-please-enter-in-a-password-that-is-harder-to-guess-i-e-contains-a-mix-of-numbers-and-letters";
                        break;
                    case UserPasswordException.PASSWORD_INVALID:
                        errorKey = "that-password-is-invalid-please-enter-in-a-different-password";
                        break;
                    case UserPasswordException.PASSWORD_LENGTH:
                        errorKey = "that-password-is-too-short-or-too-long-please-make-sure-your-password-is-between-x-and-512-characters";
                        break;
                    case UserPasswordException.PASSWORD_NOT_CHANGEABLE:
                        errorKey = "passwords-may-not-be-changed-under-the-current-password-policy";
                        break;
                    case UserPasswordException.PASSWORD_SAME_AS_CURRENT:
                        errorKey = "your-new-password-cannot-be-the-same-as-your-old-password-please-enter-in-a-different-password";
                        break;
                    case UserPasswordException.PASSWORD_TOO_TRIVIAL:
                        errorKey = "that-password-is-too-trivial";
                        break;
                    case UserPasswordException.PASSWORD_TOO_YOUNG:
                        errorKey = "you-cannot-change-your-password-yet-please-wait-at-least-x-before-changing-your-password-again";
                        break;
                    case UserPasswordException.PASSWORDS_DO_NOT_MATCH:
                        errorKey = "the-passwords-you-entered-do-not-match-each-other-please-re-enter-your-password";
                        break;

                    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Where is this code? Which API is deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

The logic of user message error is changed in liferay 7 the type of error isn't anymore in the exception message. There are inner exception in UserPasswordException that each give the error type

```
if (upe instanceof UserPasswordException.MustNotBeEqualToCurrent) {   
       errorKey = "that-password-has-already-been-used-please-enter-in-a-different-password";    
}
```

for the list of all exceptions just see the source class https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/7.4.x/portal-kernel/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/exception/UserPasswordException.java